# Facebook Like Status Message Box in Drupal

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, drupal

I am building a Drupal website and want to have a facebook like box which create a content namely quotation in my facebook. How can I do this in drupal.. Below the box I want to display other quotations...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could read this. http://www.slideshare.net/eaton/building-twitter-in-drupal-presentation

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should look at the [Statuses (Social Microblog)](https://www.drupal.org/project/statuses) module, and combine that with the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module also. You can then also have the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module create message "entities" (which is what you get if you use the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module). And then just use the power of [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) to display those messages that got created in the format you need (page, block, etc).

The [Statuses (Social Microblog)](https://www.drupal.org/project/statuses) module is pretty self explaining. 
Here is a blueprint of what you'd need to combine it with using (integrating) it with the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module:

1. Define an appropriate Message type, using the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module. Think of Message types as similar to "Content types", which will be used to create Messages, similar to Nodes. I'd imagine that the message text you'll  want to use is similar to the eMail or messages your existing rule already produces.
2. Create a rule with a Rules Action "Create entity" (of type "Message"). Refer to the answer in '**[Which user related token(s) can be used to create a Rule for setting up a message type?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/219680/)**' for some examples, which are related to these variations of using the [Mentions](https://www.drupal.org/project/mentions) module:

   - A user gets flagged (using [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag)).
   - A user is mentioned (using [Statuses (Social Microblog)](https://www.drupal.org/project/statuses)).
3. Make sure to also add a Rules Action to pass any relevant tokens from [Statuses](https://www.drupal.org/project/statuses), via [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), as *Replacement tokens* that you can use in your Message type you created with the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module. Refer to '**[What's the purpose of "Replacement tokens" of a Message type?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/220032)**' for more details on this.
4. Use [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) to display the created messages in the format you prefer.